# Minimize the sum with regards to $p$

Tags: calculus, optimization

I need to minimize the following quantity with respect to $p$, but I don't know how to go about it. Here it is:

$$\frac {x(p+h)}{pb} + \frac{(k-1)(p+h)}{b}$$

According to my textbook the answer should be 
$$p = \sqrt \frac{xh}{k-1}$$

I tried deriving but didn't get the same result. Any ideas?

Comment: deriving works just fine. see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem reduces to minimizing
$$
{xh\over p}+{(k-1)p}=\left[\sqrt{xh\over p}-\sqrt{(k-1)p}\right]^2+2\sqrt{xh(k-1)}
$$
Equate the expression inside brackets to zero to get the desired result.

Comment: Didn't cross my mind at all. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Just differentiate in regards to $p$ and set the derivative to $0$:

$${\partial\over \partial p}\left(\frac {x(p+h)}{pb} + \frac{(k-1)(p+h)}{b}\right) $$

$$= {1\over b}{\partial\over \partial p}\left(\frac {x(p+h)}{p} + (k-1)(p+h)\right) $$

$$= {1\over b}\left({\partial\over \partial p}\left(\frac {x(p+h)}{p} \right)+ {\partial\over \partial p}\big(  (k-1)(p+h)\big)\right) $$

$$= {1\over b}\left({\partial\over \partial p}\left(x+\frac {xh}{p} \right)+ {\partial\over \partial p}\big( kp-kh-p -h\big) \right)$$

$$= {1\over b}\left(\left(-\frac {xh}{p^2} \right)+ k - 1 \right)$$

Now, set the result to zero and solve for $p$:

$$ {1\over b}\left(\left(-\frac {xh}{p^2} \right)+ k - 1 \right) = 0$$

$$\iff  \left(-\frac {xh}{p^2} \right)+ k - 1  = 0$$

$$\iff -\frac {xh}{p^2}  = 1 - k$$

$$\iff {1 \over p^2}  = -{1 - k \over xh}$$

$$\iff {p^2}  = {xh \over k - 1}$$

$$\iff {p}  = \sqrt{xh \over k - 1}$$

Comment: Thanks for your thorough answer, really appreciate it!